# Does anyone have a short Android and Cloud SQL example

Tags: android, google-cloud-sql

I realize that Google App Engine (GAE) is very powerful and I would like to determine the proper way to create the database schema (outside of Android) and start populating the database (once my Android app is deployed). Then I would like to query the database (outside of Android).  I was hoping that this would be a 10-20 line exercise but it is turning into a much harder task that I anticipated.

## Out of Band Steps

1. Create Database via command line using proper GAE authorization.
2. Query  Database via command line using proper GAE authorization.

I want to reiterate that I don't want to write Java code to create or query the database. I am more interested in using SQL or a SQL-like language directly vs. using Java.

## Android Steps

1. Insert rows into the database using proper GAE authorization, encryption, etc.

Comment: It's been over 3 years and I have moved onto MEAN (Mongo/Mongoose, Express, Angular, Node).  Now I want to run a MEAN stack on the Google Cloud.  https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mean/

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to issue SQL statements to your Cloud SQL instance:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/commandline

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/sql_prompt

As for inserting rows into the database from Android, you'll need to write a GAE app to act as a proxy.  The app can then expose a REST API or whatever API you want.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is an old post but for people finding this via search, the link below is relevant and includes a sample android code:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android

Also, the Google Eclipse pluging also supports creating an App Engine Android project, see:
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae